# Tomcat urlrewrite not working

Tags: tomcat, url-rewriting

I want to redirect from this:
/myApp/article2 to this
/index.jsp?path=article2

I have this web.xml:

```
<display-name>myApp</display-name>
<filter>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
    <param-name>logLevel</param-name>
    <param-value>WARN</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
    <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/myApp/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

and this urlrewrite.xml:

```
<rule match-type="regex">
    <condition type="request-uri" operator="notequal">^/rest/(.*)$</condition>
    <condition type="request-uri" operator="notequal">^(.*\.png)$</condition>
    <condition type="request-uri" operator="notequal">^(.*\.ico)$</condition>
    <condition type="request-uri" operator="notequal">^(.*\.css)$</condition>
    <condition type="request-uri" operator="notequal">^(.*\.js)$</condition>
    <condition type="request-uri" operator="notequal">^(.*\.jsp)$</condition>

    <from>/myApp/(.*)</from>
    <to>/index.jsp?path=$1</to>
</rule>
```

but it does not work, index.jsp is called but the url (console.log(window.location.href)) inside my app is /myApp/article2